# Logical function plotting software in Linux

Tags: graphing-functions, math-software

I want to plot function like this.

> if $x > 6000$ plot function $y = 6000+ \frac{x}{15}$ otherwise plot y = $6000$

Suggest me any open source plotting software that has linux version. I have tried *KmPlot*, *KAlgebra*, *kst* they does not seem to has such option.

*KAlgebra* supports `? ... :` notation but when I enter, it says invalid syntax. If you know how to draw this funciton in

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should check out gnuplot.  It is in almost any Linux repository.

Comment: I think I have to learn a lot for that.

Comment: Check this out:  http://www.duke.edu/~hpgavin/gnuplot.html

Comment: I have solved it by using [these commands](http://pastie.org/4177253). Now I want to know how can I keep the axis not messed up.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [GNU Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/).   This code should work out

`if 3 > 4 ezplot('x^2 + y^2 = 25'); else ezplot('x^2/4 + y^2 = 36'); end`

Comment: I don't see how this answers OP's question, in which the condition is a function of `x`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party, but for the record, one could use [Maxima](https://sourceforge.net/p/maxima) for this. Maxima constructs a plotting file and then calls Gnuplot, so it might be more convenient than calling Gnuplot directly.

Letting Gnuplot select the y range automatically:

```
plot2d (if x > 6000 then 6000 + x/15 else 6000, [x, 0, 10000]);
```

Specifying a y range:

```
plot2d (if x > 6000 then 6000 + x/15 else 6000, [x, 0, 10000], [y, 0, 11000]);
```